# Attaining the maximum possible height for a fixed element between two other fixed elements

Tags: html, css, mobile, height, fixed

Alright guys here my problem,
Im trying to make my

`<div id="content" style="margin:0 auto;"><!--AJAX Loaded Content--></div>`

take as much height as it can between my

`<div id="header" style="position:fixed;top:0;width:100%;height:300px;"></div>`

and my

`<div id="footer" style="position:fixed;bottom:0;width:100%;height:200px;"></div>`

The only css rule I have is

`html,body{position:fixed;height:100%;width:100%;}`

I tried using `height:100%;` on my `#content` but it still display as a `height:auto;`...
Also, the whole thing still needs to display properly on mobile.
So my question is: what CSS rule(s) should I add/remove to make my `#content` take the whole space between the two other `<div>`'s?

http://jsfiddle.net/8AQQg/2/

Comment: Can you make a http://jsfiddle.net ?  You shouldn't have more than one element with the same ID.

Comment: You won't be able to flow around (between) fixed elements without scripting.

Comment: It was the wrong ID I fixed it in the edit added a jsfiddle.net

Comment: Since you are using html5, there is no reason to abuse the use of `div` for headers and footers. Use the `header` and `footer` tags instead.

Comment: thanks thats actually a pretty good tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you can't flow around fixed or absolutely-positioned elements. One approach might be to use an absolutely-positioned div with the same top and bottom dimensions as the heights of your #header and #footer:

http://jsfiddle.net/G3k54/2

```
html, body {
    position:fixed;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
#header {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
}
#footer {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
}
#content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    bottom: 25px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Feel free to mention how it fails and I'll try to improve it.

Comment: What fails is that I have to use precise values (i.e. top: 35px; bottom: 25px;), I was looking for a "one-rule-fits-all" solution but if it doesn't exist with only CSS, your answer is as close as it gets!