# Bootstrap fluid-layout and full height div

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, fluid-layout

I'm currently working with the Twitter's Bootstrap and trying to get something a bit specific but can't get it working...

I would like a fluid layout with navbar, sidebar, content and footer.
Also I would like a div inside the content with a full height.

HTML

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span3">
            <div class="well sidebar-nav">
                <ul class="nav nav-list">
                    <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
                </ul>
            </div><!--/.well -->
        </div><!--/span-->

        <div class="span9">
            <div class="hero-unit">
                <h1>Hero Unit</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">
                    <div id="fullHeight" style="background-color: red">
                        <p>Full height here</p>
                    </div>
                </div><!--/span-->
            </div><!--/row-->
        </div><!--/span-->
    </div><!--/row-->

    <hr>

    <footer>
        <p>&copy; Company 2013</p>
    </footer>

</div><!--/.fluid-container-->
```

CSS

```
body {
        padding-top: 60px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
    }
    .sidebar-nav {
        padding: 9px 0;
    }

    @media (max-width: 980px) {
        /* Enable use of floated navbar text */
        .navbar-text.pull-right {
            float: none;
            padding-left: 5px;
            padding-right: 5px;
        }
    }
```

Here is jsfiddle to show you what i have/want :
http://jsfiddle.net/2nuvP/

Can someone help me to get this working ?

Tips : has I'm not sure this is possible with CSS only, I accept JS/jQuery solutions ;)
Also if your solution needs some HTML modifications this is not necessary a big deal...

Comment: It can't be done without absolutely positioning your header and footer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14986873/attaining-the-maximum-possible-height-for-a-fixed-element-between-two-other-fixe/14987834

Comment: I just tried the solution described in your post but can't get it working as I want : the Hero Unit, or whatever, that is before my "full height div" is now masked...
Or maybe I'm missing something with CSS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a go at your issue using primarily jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/uyEuN/4/

**JavaScript**

```
function resolveFullHeight() {
    $("#fullHeight").css("height", "auto");

    var h_window = $(window).height(),
        h_document = $(document).height(),
        fullHeight_top = $("#fullHeight").position().top,
        est_footerHeight = 112;

    var h_fullHeight = (-1 * (est_footerHeight + (fullHeight_top - h_document)));

    $("#fullHeight").height(h_fullHeight);
}

resolveFullHeight();

$(window).resize(function () {
    resolveFullHeight();
});
```

I have left the **HTML** alone for the most part, except for adding this div beneath the navbar.

```
<div class="spacer-fluid-60"></div>
```

The **CSS** includes new rules for setting the height of the `.spacer-fluid-60` div, 
and I also removed the `padding-top` rule for the `body` element. Investigate the jsfiddle for complete details.

In the HTML, I have added a number of duplicate filler paragraphs, and have left the majority of them commented out. Un-comment them out as necessary to play around with variations of the content height in the `#fullHeight` element and see if it still behaves as you intend it to. The minimal testing I have done so far suggests this will work.

Note: add some [throttling](http://remysharp.com/2010/07/21/throttling-function-calls/) to reduce the number of times the function gets called while scrolling.

Comment: This solution works actually pretty nice and do precisely what I want !
Just added an "on DOM change event" to automatic resize on some cases and it's good.
Big thanks !